# How to use ngClass to mark a field as valid/invalid in ng6

Tags: angular

how can I apply "is-invalid" via ngClass to a bound field that angular 6 is currently marking as ng-invalid.

Would like to use Bootstraps is-valid/is-invalid css classes to improve view of the form.

Thanks

Input is as below

```
<input type="text"
  id="text-input"
  name="text-input"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="Provide a Name"
  formControlName="elementName"
  [(ngModel)]="stepName">
```

Comment: Don't mix the template driven form with reactive form

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice - can you provide an explanation how you would therefore apply a css class of invalid if the bound entity is invalid?

Comment: if you add html5 validation attributes angular will add ng-invalid class to input element

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkpats

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```js
  private isFieldValid(field: string) {
    let control = this.form.get(field);
    return !control.valid && control.touched;
  }
 
  private displayFieldCss(field: string) {
    let result : boolean;
    result = this.isFieldValid(field);
    return {
      'has-error'   : result,
      'has-feedback': result
    };
  }
```

```html
<div [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('elementName')">
    <input type="text"
      id="text-input"
      name="text-input"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Provide a Name"
      formControlName="elementName"
      [(ngModel)]="stepName">
</div>
```

Or

```js
<input type="text"
id="text-input"
name="elementName"
class="form-control"
placeholder="Provide a Name"
formControlName="elementName"
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': form.controls.elementName.invalid && form.controls.elementName.touched}">
```

Comment: Hi Thanks fo rthe response - on the second example I receive: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Comment: I see you are also using a Reactive Forms..so try to do :

[ngClass]="form.controls.elementName.invalid && form.controls.elementName.touched ? 'is-invalid' : ''">

and add this css:
   input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

Comment: Actually the css will do the trick:
    input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
        border: 1px solid red;
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<!-- add the class 'text-success' if the variable 'awesome' is true -->
<div ng-class="{ 'text-success': awesome, 'text-large': giant }">
```

Please refer the ngClass uUsing evaluated expression section [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass). It may help.

Comment: HI Thanks - is that Angular JS process - Im using Angular CLI/v6 Thanks